# Google Checkout report download through HTTP Auth

Tags: perl, google-checkout

As i am trying automate google checkout sales order report(In order to track one of our andriod app sales), i am trying to achieve this through a simple perl script(using Mechanize).

Below are the steps I am following:

1. Connecting with my google checkout order inbox
2. Accessing the target URL : https://checkout.google.com/cws/v2/AndroidMarket-1011/305286585299619/reportsForm?_type=order-list-request&column-style=&date-time-zone=America%2FLos_Angeles&end-date=2012-05-30&query-type=&start-date=2012-05-29, after logging in. I want to make use of these parameters and values , while i am automating this script. I will pass the values dynamically. For time-being, i have hard-coded it.
3. Pass auth and SID tokens along with the header
4. Reading the response and storing it in CSV file.

NOTE : My Google checkout account doesn't have merchant key facility, since it is classic account. So, i can't use API to download the report.

Here is the Perl script that i am using..

---

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp;
use CGI qw'standard';
use strict;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use HTTP::Cookies;
print "Content-type: text/html \n\n";
my $url = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin';
my $username = 'xxx@yyy.com';
my $password = "123456";
my $cookie_jar = HTTP::Cookies->new(file => 'cookies', autosave => 1, ignore_discard => 1);
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new(cookie_jar => $cookie_jar, autocheck => 0);
$mech->get($url);
$mech->form_id('gaia_loginform');
$mech->field(Email => $username);
$mech->field(Passwd => $password);
$mech->submit();
$cookie_jar->save;
# Go to the Google checkout orer inbox
$url = 'https://checkout.google.com/sell/orders';
$mech->get($url);
print $mech->content();
#Retain the cookie through out the page
$cookie_jar->load;
print "This request is valid.";
$mech->form_name('dateInput');
$mech->field('start-date','2012-05-30');
$mech->field('end-date','2012-06-01');
$mech->field('date-time-zone','America/Los_Angeles');
$mech->field('_type','order-list-request');
$cookie_jar->load;
my $results = $mech->submit();
my $response = $mech->res();
my $filename = $response->filename;
if (! open ( FOUT, ">$filename" ) ) {
    die("Could not create file: $!" );
}
print( FOUT $m->response->content() );
close( FOUT );
print $results->content();
```

---

Here is the result..

Script says "HTTP Error 400: Bad Request". As i understand that, URL format which i sent through is not producing my desired output as well as prompting an error.

Just wondering, whether there is any work around already in place to achieve this via HTTP call and query string passing like i have done in script, as there is no merchant key available for my account.

Thanks  - Looking forward to hear from you. Appreciate your help !

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you only have an Android In-App Billing Merchant account, but not a Google Checkout Merchant account.

In order to use the Order API (or other Google Checkout APIs) you need have a Merchant Key which you can get if your account is also a classic Checkout Merchant account.

Use the url below to sign up for the Checkout Merchant account. Make sure to use the same Google login credentials as your existing merchant account:

http://checkout.google.com/sell/signup

Answer (score 0):

You can not leave 'financial-state' parameter empty.

Set a valid value

```
$mech->field('financial-state', 'CHARGEABLE');
```

or just delete it.